# Find and return element in (deep) object

Tags: jsonnet

I'll write "pseudo-python-jsonnet" code to show what I want to achieve.
I really have no clue how to do something like that in jsonnet.

```
local createCopy(gname, rname, kp) =                                        
    for topLvlKey in std.objectFieldsAll(kp):                                   
        for subKey in std.objectFieldsAll(kp[topLvlKey]):                       
            if kp[topLvlKey][subKey].get("kind", "") == "PrometheusRule":       
                for group in kp[topLvlKey][subKey]["spec"]["groups"]:           
                    if group["name"] == gname:                              
                        for rule in group["rules"]:                             
                            if rule.get("alert", "") == rname:              
                                return rule
                        return null                                    
    return null
```

So basically I want to search a deep object structure for a specific sub-object and return it or return null/None if it is not found.

https://jsonnet.org/learning/tutorial.html is somehow good, but only shows the "easy" parts, if you want to do more complex things with jsonnet, it seems you're left on your own. I'm new to jsonnet and it really gives me headaches, so I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below scriptlet implements it

```
// filterArray by func() (returning bool)
local filterArray(array, func) = [elem for elem in array if func(elem)];

// search Prometheus' rule groups by groupName, alertName
local getPrometheusRule(groups, groupName, alertName) = (
  local group = filterArray(groups, function(x) std.objectHas(x, 'name') && x.name == groupName);
  if std.length(group) > 0
  then (
    assert std.length(group) == 1 : 'Duplicated group.name "%s"' % groupName;
    local rule = filterArray(group[0].rules, function(x) std.objectHas(x, 'alert') && x.alert == alertName);
    if std.length(rule) > 0
    then (
      assert std.length(rule) == 1 : 'Duplicated alert "%s"' % alertName;
      rule[0]
    )
  )
);

local createCopy(gname, rname, kp) = [
  if std.objectHas(kp[topLvlKey][subKey], 'kind') && kp[topLvlKey][subKey].kind == 'PrometheusRule'
  then getPrometheusRule(kp[topLvlKey][subKey].spec.groups, gname, rname)
  for topLvlKey in std.objectFieldsAll(kp)
  for subKey in std.objectFieldsAll(kp[topLvlKey])
];

/* Simple unit-tests follow */

local stack = {
  fooService: {
    fooResource: {
      kind: 'PrometheusRule',
      spec: {
        groups: [
          { name: 'fooGroup', rules: [{ alert: 'fooAlert', expr: 'fooExpr' }] },
          { name: 'barGroup', rules: [{ alert: 'fooAlert', expr: 'fooExpr' }] },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
};

{
  test_01_Found: createCopy('fooGroup', 'fooAlert', stack),
  test_02_NotFound: createCopy('fooGroup', 'fooAlerX', stack),
  test_03_NotFound: createCopy('fooGrouX', 'fooAlert', stack),
}
```

Although depending on your specific *problem*, you may want to look at https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/blob/master/README.md#customising-alert-annotations for `utils.mapRuleGroups()` approach (granted it rather *mutates* rule(s)).

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot! 
This helps me, not only with my actual problem but also to further understand the nature of jsonnet.